# Installation hangs at 73% - admin cookie set with expired date

Tags: magento2, installation, cookie

The installation proceeds normally until the console log gets to:

```
Module 'Magento_Weee':
Installing data...
```

At this point (73%) the user experience just hangs, while the browser repeatedly requests prolong and unlogin. It appears that at this point in the installation, a cookie `admin` is issued with an expiration date set in the past - This installation is on **Centos/Cloudlinux 7** with **Litespeed**.

Can anyone hazard a guess at why this may be happening?

[Installation point of failure screenshot](https://www.evernote.com/shard/s276/sh/bc1395d0-8950-4172-8656-74446529f95c/9e845c208fe55c37/res/7c61cfd2-bd6c-4cb6-8fd0-9921df4e65d4/skitch.png)

Comment: I presuming that you are installing Magento 2.

Comment: Try to install in private window of browser

Comment: Try install with terminal/CMD

Comment: Yes - Magento 2 latest - yes, tried in different browsers FF/Ch/Saf in private sessions,  and yes it will install fine from terminal. But this is part of a larger problem preventing the web installation in tandem with Installatron, so I must determine why the web installation method is failing.

Comment: have you checked Magento 2 logs and reports, also it shows error in AJAX request.

Comment: Yep - nothing in var/log/* (literally, no log entries anything near the time of the installation), and var/reports doesn't exist...

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

Magento 2 install by command. Here is the command for that:

> php bin/magento setup:install --base-url={store URL} --db-host={DB
>   host} --db-name={DB name} --db-user={DB user name} --db-password={DB
>   password} --admin-firstname={admin user first name}
>   --admin-lastname={admin user last name} --admin-email={admin user Email ID} --admin-user={admin user name admin user will login with
>   this user name} --admin-password={admin user password}
>   --language={default store language} --currency={default store currency} --timezone={default store time zone} --use-rewrites={store
>   will use rewrites}

Here is the sample code :

> php bin/magento setup:install
>   --base-url=http://demo.magento225sample.com/ --db-host=localhost --db-name=magento225Sample --db-user=root --db-password= --admin-firstname=kunj --admin-lastname=joshi --admin-email=test.test@example.com --admin-user=admin --admin-password=admin@123 --language=en_US --currency=USD --timezone=America/Chicago --use-rewrites=1

Comment: Yes, it will install fine from the command line. Sorry, I should have clarified that. The problem only occurs when installing using the web interface.

Answer (score 2):

I think Installation proccess will stuck cz of memory_limit.

Please check below link and then try to install. Also Change in php.ini.

```
max_execution_time = 1800
max_input_time = 1800
memory_limit = 1024M
```

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/apache.html http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/system-requirements.html

Comment: These were the first things we checked - and all exceed those stated above.